# Nodejs serverside debugging

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I am trying to learn NodeJS along with AngularJS. On the frontend, I can simply put `debugger` statement when I want to put a breakpoint and debug from the browser console. How can I put breakpoints from the server side? In other words, I am looking for a function like `pdb` in nodejs version.

More specifically, I am trying to learn how to upload files using angularjs on the front and express on the back. When I submit a form with a file attached, a POST request is sent to the server with a set of parameters. Then, the server must submit this form to Amazon S3 with the appropriate credentials. I want to set a breakpoint before submitting the form to Amazon S3 to check the params.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector 
try this node-inspector, allow you to debug the nodejs just like debugging frontend codes in the chrome devtool

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try for visionmedia [debug](https://github.com/visionmedia/debug) module.

You may require to configure your node app on your server app.js/main.js/web.js which actually bootstrap your node server app.

```
var debug = require('debug')('YOUR-APP-NAME');
```